# Unable to convert a string tuple into a regular tuple in python

Tags: python, string, tuples, psycopg2

I have a database select output obtained using `psycopg2`. The output looks like below

```
result = [('("",Loc,001)',), ('(London,Loc,002)',), ('(Tokyo,Loc,006)',), ('("New York","New Loc",TEST2)',), ('(Berlin,Loc,TEST1)',), ('(Dubai,Loc,TEST4)',)]
```

This output has been obtained against a distinct query I ran on multiple columns something like

```
SELECT distinct(col1, col2, col3) from table;
```

But the output is very complicated to process since some strings inside each tuple don't have a quote.

I tried doing something like below

```
import ast
formatted_result = [item[0] for item in result]
print(ast.literal_eval(formatted_result))
```

But it throws the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(ast.literal_eval(formatted_result))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 79, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string
```

The other option is going though each tuple, split by comma and remove unnecessary characters like below

```
for item in formatted_result:
    col1 = item.split(",")[0].replace('(', "").replace( ")", "").replace('"', "")
    col2 = item.split(",")[1].replace('(', "").replace( ")", "").replace('"', "")
    col3 = item.split(",")[2].replace('(', "").replace( ")", "").replace('"', "")
```

What is the proper way to process this output?

Comment: "This output has been obtained against a distinct query I ran on multiple columns something like" Something seems rather strange about the database schema here. Could you show an example of what the `table` might look like, along with the *exact actual* query, and the corresponding data retrieved by your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using brackets around your columns is going to return a `row-construct`, that's why your output looks messed up.

```
query = "select distinct(ts, popularity) from table where id < 28050"
cur.execute(query)
print(cur.fetchall())
>>> [('(1640082115,23)',), ('(1640082115,28)',), ...]
```

Whereas the same query without brackets is going to return the expected result:

```
query = "select distinct ts, popularity from table where id < 28050"
cur.execute(query)
print(cur.fetchall())
>>> [(1640082115, 23), (1640082115, 28), (1640082116, 51), ...]
```

Comment: oh I see now. Didn't know that. Thanks for pointing that out!